# How to crop interiour of a contour?

Tags: python, pycharm, contour

I am new to image processing and also new to python. Can you explain properly about how to get the results? Here is my code :

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread("C:\\Users\\shashisanha\\Desktop\\shapes.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
_, threshold = cv2.threshold(img, 240, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
contours,_=cv2.findContours(threshold, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
for cnt in contours:
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt , 0.01*cv2.arcLength(cnt, True), True)
    cv2.drawContours(img,[approx],0,(0) , 5)
    if len(approx)==3:
        print(3)
cv2.imshow("shape",img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This is only for finding contour and now I want to crop it up.

Answer (score 0):

First you find the dimensions of the boundingbox of the contour:
`x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)`
Then you create a new image that holds the region of the boundingrect:
`subimg = img[y:y+h,x:x+w]`